# How to avoid copying / creating new node when inserting into a BST

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, binary-search-tree, sml

Let's ignore the balancing part of the BST for now.

```
type 'a bst = 
  | Leaf
  | Node of 'a bst * 'a * 'a bst
```

A typical `insert` will look like this:

```
let rec insert x = function
  | Leaf -> Node (Leaf, x, Leaf)
  | Node (l, k, r) as n ->
    if x = k then n
    else if x < k then Node (insert x l, k, r)
    else Node (l, k, insert x r)
```

No doubts, the function `insert` will `create new nodes / make a copy of nodes` along the search path.

So my question is **is there a way to avoid this copying?**

This question comes from `Exercise 2.3` of the book [Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0521663504/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d5_i1?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_r=05QS3HG7J9YJPE2271EP&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=430173587&pf_rd_i=468294):

> Exercise 2.3 Inserting an existing eleemtn into a binary search tree
>   copies the entire search path even though the copied nodes are
>   indistinguishable from the originals. Rewrite insert using exceptions
>   to avoid this copying. Establish only one handler per insertion rather
>   than one handler per iteration.

I actually quite don't follow the exercise.

1. What does it mean by "using exceptions to avoid this copying"?
2. Why use "exceptions"?
3. What means "one handler per insertion"?

Comment: Oh man, I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out too. Totally missed the _existing_ element bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the copying is avoidable only when inserting an element that's already there! It shouldn't be too hard to see how to do this.

Comment: ahh, ok, I thought it can be totally avoided

Comment: wait, r u sure about this? Should I just do a `mem` test before real insertion?

Comment: If you read the text you copied it says "inserting an *existing* element into a binary search tree..." (emphasis mine). You can just do mem test, sure. Just a small constant slowdown. You could throw exception from the bottom of the search, pass back extra state, etc.

Comment: i stared at that question for over an hour before seeing the word "existing" on stack overflow:/